# powershell writing to a log file

Tags: file, logging, powershell

I've written the code below which works fine apart from one of the variables is over 200 characters and goes onto the next line messing the layout up.  Any suggestions on a better layout so if one of the variables is long, it still retains structure?

```
$WriteLog = $null 
$WriteLog = @()
$WriteLog +="Here is some stuff:                $stuff1"
$WriteLog +="Here is some stuff:                $stuff2"
$WriteLog +="Here is some stuff:                $stuff3"
$WriteLog +="Here is some stuff:                $stuff4"
$WriteLog +="Here is some stuff:                $stuff5"
$WriteLog +="Here is some stuff:                $stuff6"
Out-File -InputObject $WriteLog -Append -NoClobber -FilePath "$env:SystemDrive\somestuff\somestuff.txt"
```

Example output :

```
"Here is some stuff:                    stuff1"
"Here is some stuff:            stuff2"  
"Here is some stuff:                Heres a lot of stuff
stuff3, stuff3, stuff3, stuff3,  stuff3, stuff3" 
"Here is some stuff:            stuff4"  
"Here is some stuff:                    stuff5"
"Here is some stuff:                    stuff6"
```

Comment: As you can see ive updated the original question with a example. everything kind of lines up until "Heres a lot of stuff
stuff3" and then it wraps onto the next line.  I would like it to all justifie with stuff one and if it wraps onto the next line, again justify with stuff1.  Hope i make a little more sence now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use formatting if you are not sure (I hope I understand your problem). See

```
'{0,5} -f 5
#vs.
'{0,5} -f 1115
```

Then..

```
$WriteLog = $stuff1, $stuff2, $stuff3, $stuff4, $stuff5, $stuff6 | 
               Foreach-Object { "Here is some stuff:{0,20}" -f $_ }
$WriteLog = $WriteLog -join "`n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Out-File has a -Width parameter that might help.  Or can you format the long variable as a here string?